# Can I get Apache2 to use rolling log files without restarting on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, logging

From what i found on the web, "the way" to make Apache2 use rolling log files is to write a cron job that stop apache, rolls the log file, and starts it again.

Is there a saner way that doesn't force an apache shutdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify what operating system, so I'm going to assume you're on a Linux system. In CentOS, the logrotate "daemon" already has this written out for you. When it rotates the log, it uses the `httpd reload` command, which to my understanding does not exit the apache process, meaning no requests are rejected during that short interval. Try and look in `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd` for the rules. If that file doesn't exist, you can easily make one based off of any of the other rules you'll find in the logrotate.d folder.

Comment: Thanks - I'm using Ubuntu, and I found the config in /etc/logrotate.d/apache2

Answer (score 2):

You can use Piped Logs as described here: [Piped Logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html#piped)